# How is this M(2,2)->R closed under addition?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

so I understand that It is closed under scalar multiplication, but how is it closed under addition? what if I add another matrix to A? and create new a,b,c,d values?

Comment: "Closed under addition" is not quite the right phrase here.  We use the properties of being closed under scalar multiplication and closed under addition to define vector spaces (with other properties), but the issue here is whether $T$ is a *linear transformation*, i.e. a mapping from one vector space to another that *preserves* operations of scalar multiplication and vector addition.

Comment: ohhh okay thank you that clarified that for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Help me fill this in:

\begin{align*}
T \begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1 \end{pmatrix} &= \underline{\hspace{50pt}} \in \mathbb{R} \\
T \begin{pmatrix}a_2 & b_2 \\ c_2 & d_2 \end{pmatrix} &= \underline{\hspace{50pt}} \in \mathbb{R} \\
T \begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1 \end{pmatrix} +T \begin{pmatrix}a_2 & b_2 \\ c_2 & d_2 \end{pmatrix} &= \underline{\hspace{50pt}} \in \mathbb{R} \\
\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}a_2 & b_2 \\ c_2 & d_2 \end{pmatrix} &= \underline{\hspace{50pt}} \in M_{2, 2} \\
T\left(\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}a_2 & b_2 \\ c_2 & d_2 \end{pmatrix}\right) &= \underline{\hspace{50pt}} \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{align*}
Are your answers to questions 3 and 5 the same? If so, then $T$ is additive. You can try a similar tactic with scalar multiplication. Let me know with a comment if you want further help.

Answer (score 0):

TIP: the sum of two matrices is a matrix. Try writing $T(A)$ in terms of the values of this matrix and, after expanding each term (because they're bound on the other two matrices), compare the final expression two the other two expressions.